# PyCharm using wrong path for files

Tags: java, pycharm

I have two separate repositories with source code (different branches initially created through Perforce). The first I opened in PyCharm by creating a new Project pointing to the repository. This was working fine and dandy.

However, after creating the second project pointing to the second repo, I noticed that debugging the code, and using Go To Declaration on a class method would take me to the correct file, but in the wrong repo (wrong path). I could open the correct file path directly in PyCharm, but any attempt to go to or step into references in other files would resolve to the incorrect file path.

First thing I tried was clearing the cache in C:\Users\[user]\.PyCharm30, deleting the .idea folder, even Invalidating the Cache from the File Menu.

When that didn't work I searched for the offending path and found a file in C:\Users\[user]\.PyCharm30\config\options called jdk.table.xml. This must be where PyCharm is getting hints to resolve paths. I deleted all the root urls in here that referenced the wrong path, and saved, restarted PyCharm. This time PyCharm couldn't resolve the references at all. Attempting to Go To Declaration would show "Cannot find declaration to go to".

What's more, attempting to Invalidate the Cache restored the offending lines to jdk.table.xml.

I'm not sure where this file is getting these classpaths from. This is related to the JDK class path, but I'm not sure how. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the incorrect directory entries in [usr].PyCharm30\config\options\jdk.table.xml, close the conflicting project and restart pycharm.

I know you tried the first step, but maybe your experience is due to trying to keep using both of the conflicting projects, in which case when pycharm restarts it is trying to rebuild both into the global jdk.table.xml.